# How to parse json array having dynamic keys using Retrofit 2

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I am trying to fetch json response using retrofit 2. My json response looks like this :

```
[
    0 : {
        type : "video",
        format : "mp4",
        size : "10mb"
        },
    1 : {
        type : "audio",
        format : "mp3",
        size : "10mb"
        },
    2 : {
        type : "text",
        format : "pdf",
        size : "10mb"
        }
]
```

How should my model class look like? I can't understand as it has dynamic keys.

Comment: What library are you using to parse? gson? jackson? anyways, that is an array, so parsing it to an array of a class (that has type, format and size) should be straight forward.

Comment: I am using gson

Comment: as they already said, the json is invalid, once is valid, you shouldn't have any issues to parse it. Im attaching an example below

Comment: Your example doesn't have dynamic keys, but, if it did, you could look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36780871/gson-deserialize-json-array-with-multiple-object-types

Comment: @EricCochran, I meant different keys . Here it has 0,1,2.

Comment: @N.K.T Okay, if you meant to put those numbers there, then that is not valid JSON, as the answers below state.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a valid Json as you can try that on https://jsonlint.com/ , you can change your response to :

```
[  
   {  
      "type":"video",
      "format":"mp4",
      "size":"10mb"
   },
   {  
      "type":"audio",
      "format":"mp3",
      "size":"10mb"
   },
   {  
      "type":"text",
      "format":"pdf",
      "size":"10mb"
   }
]
```

Answer (score 3):

first of all this is invalid/incomplete JSON. The valid version would look something like this

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "0": {
        "type": "video",
        "format": "mp4",
        "size": "10mb"
      }
    },
    {
      "1": {
        "type": "audio",
        "format": "mp3",
        "size": "10mb"
      }
    },
    {
      "2": {
        "type": "text",
        "format": "pdf",
        "size": "10mb"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

and it would safely deserialize to this

```
    class Item{
        String type;
        String format;
        String size;
    }

    class Response{
        List<Map<Integer,Item>> items;
    }


//....

Response response = new Gson().fromJson(yourJson, Response.class);
```

As an alternative solution, as I am sure you can't change the JSON format, change the [] to {} in your JSON string and deserialize it like this

```
Map fieldMap = (Map)new Gson().fromJson(json, Map.class);
```

it should give you a LinkedTreeMap of all your data

Comment: Why a list of maps?, the json should be more simple, like the one presented by @Arash. Response should be a List of Item.

Comment: I'm not sure 0:{something} works like  list.add(0,something) in GSON. ":"
 usually means key/value. ["1","2","3"] : this surely does deserialize into a valid java list.

Comment: but if you are changing the json to make it valid, you can change that...

Comment: @MatiasOlocco in some situations one can't change the remote WS to fit one's requirements (public API, 3rd party lib, no access, bad devs). At this point, a small client-side change of first and last chars in the JSON string is almost acceptable, provided that you can easily work with it afterwards and it helps you avoid useless boxings in the code. Changing it to the fully correct version of it (my first example or other answers) isn't something would/could do from the client code. so yes, if I couldn't change the remote JSON source, I would go for [ ] to { } and turn it into a Map<Item>

Comment: I know that.. but you changed the json entirely.., and you stated how a valid version should look, and then your valid version is not optimal, that was my whole point, if you get to change the json, why doing it like in your example when it can be done in a better way. Sorry, but it is like that.

Comment: @MatiasOlocco change the received json entirely on the client side? is that something you would do? I'd be ok with a small change (first and last chars) if it gave a solid advantage in deserialization, but changing the internal structure and fields would involve a lot of heavy and error prone string manipulation, which is an absolute NOT.

Comment: You didn't change that only, please check your json. You converted the array into an object. You added "items", and you changed each element from 0:{} to be {0:{}}, so, how is that error free? and how is that just changing first and last character???? on top of that, I never suggested to do it in client side and as far as we concern, he might be able to change it in the server side... Seriously, I'm done with this discussion.

Comment: yeah, we're losing it. perhaps if you carefully read my posts again it'll make a little sense, but that wouldn't make the json better in any way :) have a nice and productive day

Answer (score 2):

So, as people already said, if you change your json to be valid:

```
[  
   {  
      "type":"video",
      "format":"mp4",
      "size":"10mb"
   },
   {  
      "type":"audio",
      "format":"mp3",
      "size":"10mb"
   },
   {  
      "type":"text",
      "format":"pdf",
      "size":"10mb"
   }
]
```

Then you can create your class, for instance:

```
public class Test {
    public String type;
    public String format;
    public String size;
}
```

And then, with Gson:

```
Type testType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Test>>(){}.getType();
ArrayList<Test> list = new Gson().fromJson(json, testType);
```

On the other hand, with retrofit2 you can get the [Gson converter](https://github.com/square/retrofit/wiki/Converters) to do the job for you.