# How to deserialize Json with the class being provided as part of the Json using Gson?

Tags: java, json, gson, deserialization

A doozy of a title, isn't it? But really it refers to something very simple. Say I have the following Json:

```
{
  "type": "me.example.game.FireballSkill" 
  "data": {
    "damage": 500.0,
    "cost": 20.0,
    "cooldown": 10000
  }
}
```

And then lets presume the class FireballSkill extends AbstractSkill, which itself implements an interface Castable.

I need to somehow take the above, find the class from the "type" tag, and then deserialize the "data" Json object into an instance of the class I would have gotten from "type".

Is this even possible? Is there a better way to do it? Can I even do it this way, would it work?

Comment: You *can* do that.  You could extract the class name, use `Class.forName()` to get the class object, and pass it and the "data" json into gson.  What are you trying to accomplish here?  Do you really have no better way to determine the type you want to map the json into than embedding it in the message?

Comment: Well, I'd really like to create a Deserializer for Castables, which is an interface. And naturally the data in the Json is going to be representing a specific class which implements Castable in either a direct or indirect way. So the purpose of embedding the class name into the Json is so the CastableDeserializer knows what the hell it's meant to be deserializing :)

Comment: You'll want a TypeAdapter that buffers the whole value and delegates to the concrete types' TypeAdapters. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36780871/gson-deserialize-json-array-with-multiple-object-types) which has the same premise.
Also, Gson has an example of a pluggable [RuntimeTypeAdadpterFactory](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/855f0493d0edba5d6f6ec4c72a46bfef225ef22c/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/typeadapters/RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.java).